# How was the solution to this recurrence obtained?

Tags: induction, recursive-algorithms

I am trying to understand the solution to the following recurrence.
$I(n) = 1+n/B$ if $n \leq \alpha M$ and $I(n) = 4I(n/2)+1$ otherwise.

The solution, according to the paper this is from, is $I(n) = 1+n/B+n^{2}/(BM)$. The authors provide no proof and it does not appear correct to me, and solving the recurrence explicitly, I obtained $I(n) = n^{3}/(\alpha^{2}M^{2}B)$. I am not sure who is wrong, so any help is appreciated.

Note: $\alpha$ may be assumed to be a constant, i.e. 1. However, $B$ and $M$ are variables that must be included in the final answer.

Comment: The solution provided by the paper is wrong. Indeed, let's take $n/2 > \alpha M$, then one has $4I(n/2) + 1 = 5 + \frac{2n}{B} + \frac{n^2}{BM} \neq I(n)$.

Comment: You can just check the formula yours and the given, by taking a fixed M say M=10 and find $I_{10}=1+\frac{10}{B) $ so both  are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $n = \alpha M$ we have $I(\alpha M)=1+\alpha\frac MB$. Now regarding

$$
I(n) = 4 I\left(\frac n2\right)+1
$$

making $n= 2^m$ we have $I\left(2^m\right) = 4 I\left(2^{m-1}\right)+1$. This recurrence can be recasts as

$$
r(m) = 4r(m-1)+1
$$

with solution

$$
r(m) = \frac 13(4^m-1)+ c_0 4^{m-1}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

now taking $m =  \log_2 n$ we have

$$
I(n) = \frac 13(4^{\log_2 n}-1)+ c_0 4^{\log_2 n-1} = \frac{1}{12} \left((3 c_0+4) n^2-4\right)
$$

such that $I(\alpha M)=1+\alpha\frac MB$ so we have

$$
c_0 = \frac{4}{3} \left(\frac{3 \alpha  M+4 B}{\alpha ^2 B M^2}-1\right)
$$

and finally

$$
I(n) = \frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{n^2 (3 \alpha  M+4 B)}{\alpha ^2 B M^2}-1\right)
$$

NOTE

As $(1)$ is a linear recurrence it can be solved as follows:

$$
\cases{
r_h(m) = 4 r_h(m-1)\\
r_p(m) = 4 r_p(m-1) + 1 \\
r(m) = r_h(m) + r_p(m)
}
$$

now, the solution for the homogeneous is

$$
r_h(m) = c_04^{m-1}
$$

now choosing a particular such that $r_p(m) = c_0(m)4^m$ after substitution we obtain

$$
c_0(m)4^m = c_0(m-1)4^m + 1\Rightarrow c_0(m) = c_0(m-1) + \frac{1}{4^m}
$$

hence $c_0(m) = \sum_k \frac{1}{4^k} = \frac{1-4^{-m}}{1-4^{-1}}= \frac 134(1-4^{-m})$ and $r_p(m) = \frac 13(4^m-1)$

Comment: This is great! Could you explain further how you got from $r(m) = 4r(m-1) + 1$ to $r(m) = 1/3 (4^{m}-1) + c_{0}4^{m-1}$.

Comment: Please. See attached note.